# Quickbooks Web Connect

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have been doing a lot of research on QuickBooks Web Connector. I have to integrate QuickBooks with my website's SQL Server. I will be coding this in PHP. What I need to it do is when a member completes a form online I want the web connector to create an Invoice or account if it is a new account. What I can't seem to find out is if I use QuickBooks Web Connector can the following:

**Questions:**
1. Can the web connector create a new account in Quickbooks? (I believe this is possible)

1. What happens if this account is already created in QuickBooks can I just create/add an invoice to this account then?

The follow resources just show you kind of how to setup the Connector with QuickBooks:

http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector?

http://whiterabbitservices.com/2011/11/19/quickbooks-web-connector-when-to-use-it/

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Can the web connector create a new account in Quickbooks?

Yes.

You can find the full list of things that the QuickBooks SDK (and thus the Web Connector) supports here:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html

  (use the "Select Message" drop-down box)

It's probably worth noting that in QuickBooks an `Account` is an account in the accounting sense of the word - for example, a "bank account", a "checking account", a "credit card account", an "accounts receivable account", etc.

It sounds like you're probably talking about a `Customer`, not an account.

You might also find these qbXML example requests helpful:

- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/Example_qbXML_Requests
- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks

> What happens if this account is already created in QuickBooks can I just create/add an invoice to this account then?

It's really up to you. You could certainly just add an invoice to the existing customer, sure. Alternatively, if you wanted to do something else (throw an error, create a duplicate customer, etc.), you could do something else too.

Comment: Wow thank you! Yes I am Account = Customer. When you create a new Invoice how do you tell if the Customer already exist? Is there a command you can send to QB saying hey is this account here? I took a look at your SDK Developer link above but I'm a little confused how to use it. Do you have any docs or help you could provide me to help me understand how to use that? Again thank you for the resources of links!

Comment: You can do a CustomerQuery to find out if the customer already exists... but you're usually better off just always issuing a CustomerAdd to make sure the customer exists, catch the error if the customer already exists, then doing an InvoiceAdd after that using the customer name. Follow the quick-start: http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Quick-Start  If you have more questions, we have support forums here: http://www.consolibyte.com/forum/

Comment: Oh I'm sure I have plenty of questions. But thank you for the head start!! Looking for to it!